# Rendered image is blank, or white, or shows as a text file in the filebrowser

Tags: rendering, image

[image: This is my render setting]

[image: Rendered file, this should be png but it is just white file.]

First image is render setting. And second image is output file. That file should be png file but, it is not.

Comment: Do you have a light in your scene? Do you have a camera in your scene? Please include a .blend file: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file Thanks!

Comment: yes. I have many lights and cameras.

Comment: Sounds good! May you include the .blend file so we can check the problem? Thanks!

Comment: My file is so big it won't let me upload in both website.

Comment: just add a .png extension to the name.

Comment: @nice_cat If it is too big then it is best to reduce your file to a minimum working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Windows (and other operating systems) doesn't know what to do with files that have no file extension.

Just rename the file and the extension that corresponds with the file format (in this case .png,), so that the OS understands it is dealing with an image (or video) file and uses the appropriate program to open such file.

In the future enable the **File Extensions** box on the output so that you get the name with a .png (or .exr or .jpg or mp4 or whatever) extension.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! finally. Thank you sususu