# Rendered file is unreadable

Tags: rendering

When I render an animation, and attempt to view the file it's just a blank icon that says it's a .avi, but none of my software can view it or even see that it's there. I know it's not a compatibility issue because I have other .avi on my computer that I can view.

I am rendering in Eevee viewport at 16 samples on a mac + 2.8 and 3.2 for render tests. I tried restarting my compouter, reinstalling blender, using an older version of my blend file. Kinda at my wit's end here and I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: 'I know it's not a compatibility issue because I have other .avi on my computer that I can view.' Well that still could be the actual issues. AVI is just a container, it can have videos made out of many codecs, some of which you might not have support for. What are your codec settings in Blender? Also, consider not exporting in video at all ; check [Why render in image sequences and which formats to use](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263176/no-rgba-option-in-render-output-panel/263188#263188)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182033/rendered-image-is-blank-or-white-or-shows-as-a-text-file-in-the-filebrowser https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201450/blender-will-not-render-any-videos/